# how to submit the form values using ajax call, without using submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application.

I want to submit the form using ajax function, not using standard submit button click event.

I want to pass object of the model along with string array (which is not related to object of the model.)

I have below code in Create View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdviceCreate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmCreate", onsubmit = "disableSubmitButton()" }))
```

{
}

```
  $('#create').click(function () {

            alert("create")

            var count = $(".clsInvoiceId").length;
            var invoiceDetailsArray = new Array();
            var ledgerDetailsArray = new  Array();

            var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';



            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',           
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "AdviceCreate")',
                type: 'POST',    

                data:
                JSON.stringify({ 
                    AdviceCreateVM : obj,
                    InvoiceDetails : invoiceDetailsArray,
                    LedgerDetails  : ledgerDetailsArray

                }),              
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        });
```

and below code in controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AdviceCreateVM AdviceCreateVM, string[] InvoiceDetails, string[] LedgerDetails)
 {
}
```

but in controller, AdviceCreateVM  comes as NULL ...

what is missing ?

Comment: did u tried alert on `alert(obj)` before submitting ?

Comment: show the output of `obj` coz i guess you are outputing string and the model binder can't bind the type to `AdviceCreateVM`

Comment: @ DotNet Dreamer, please explain , didn't understand...

Comment: what does this `var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';` returns?

Comment: can you try with jQuery.parseJSON() and see if you get the valid return for obj = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

Comment: @ DotNet Dreamer , Its returning NULL values...

Comment: Have you checked your Model has this some value in it before you encode it ?

Comment: so then you have to check your `Create()` Get action method in controller and make sure you are passing data to the view. check using breakpoints

Comment: Its a create view, no data is passed in create() get mothod, there are about 7 text box, which are strongly binded with model.

Comment: you have to pass the data to the view. if not how `Json.Encode(Model)` model knows what to encode. please check this `http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view`. Model only gets the data comming from view.

Comment: But I have made these textboxes strongly typed... how come I send first name, last name values in create method, user should fill and submit...

Comment: @ codebased, didn't worked...

Comment: then try with jquery and get the values of thoses textboxes ` $("textboxid").val();` and make your local model manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to manually submit a form on a button click and along with it,you want to supply extra data.

Edit: Corrected some mistakes.  here is working [Example in .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DK3mPN) check console.log output in fiddle. Removed content-Type, as we are customizing it, jquery ajax will auto detect it.

```
$('#create').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault(); 
            alert("create")

            var count = $(".clsInvoiceId").length;
            var invoiceDetailsArray = new Array();
            var ledgerDetailsArray = new  Array();

            //If you have validation attached, then you need to validate the form first and before submit if form is valid. 

            var obj =$("#frmCreate").serializeArray(); //serializeArray gives you a name,value object
            //Append extra data to above name/value collection,   
            obj.push({name: 'InvoiceDetails', value: invoiceDetailsArray});
            obj.push({name: 'LedgerDetails', value: ledgerDetailsArray});

            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "AdviceCreate")',
                type: 'POST',    

                data:
               obj,              
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...but still at controller level, object doesn't contain any values all properties are blank...

Answer (score 1):

Normally I do this:

```
var postData = $("#form1").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',           
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "AdviceCreate")',
                type: 'POST',    

                data: postData

                success: function () {

                }
            });
```

Comment: No, I want to send the object and array separately , because, I make array run time...

Comment: @user1650894, Your can use `var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();` and add additional data using `data.push({InvoiceDetails: 'invoiceDetailsArray', LedgerDetails: ledgerDetailsArray});`

Comment: About to say that... mate push push push :)

Answer (score 0):

your view is rendered before your button click function is called (becuase you are making client side call). so your code

```
var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

is null becuase `Model` is comming null from controller. So as you are saying, you are getting the values from dynamic textboxes, then the right way is to get the data on client side (i.e using jQuery or javascript) and manually make a javascript array and pass it to the server or you have to catch the data on serverside in controller after the form is posted to the server.
Inshort, if you are thinking the code;

```
var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

will get the data after client side click, then you are on the wrong track.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... then what the solution for it ?